# how to not select an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

On mobile, I want to have an event handler only for the actual text in the anchor tag, and not the svg. At the moment clicking on either the svg or the text, which is essentially the href tag has the same result.

Basically, clicking the svg should not have the same effect as clicking on the text.

The html:

```
<li class="has-child">
    <a href="https://example.com">Example<svg>+</svg></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

   $( 'li.has-child a' ).on('click', function(e) {
       alert('...');
   });
```

Comment: Easiest solution is to put the text in a `span` then target `li.has-child a>span`.  Can you change the HTML?

Comment: @freedomn-m brilliant idea, works well it would seem. If you add that as an official answer I can mark as such.